# Installing "Differences"-palette from AuthorTools

Tags: packages

I am new to this feature of Mathematica.
In Mathematica 10.0, how do I load/use "AuthorTools"? I am particularly interested in installing the "Differences" palette
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the package using

```
Needs["AuthorTools`"]
```

The name Differences seems unfortunate because of the name conflict with the built-in function [Differences](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences.html). Nonetheless, after loading the package, you can go to the AuthorTools/guide/AuthorTools (the AuthorTools Package Guide) and click on the word `Differences` near the bottom, and this installs the pallette.